# Virtual PC error, Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU

Tags: system-installation

I use Virtual PC with Windows 7 Unlimited version, I have AMD processor, I have installed Windows XP mode, which works fine, I would like to install Ubuntu Linux Operating System, but unable so far, I have searched in Google and still cannot fix.

The error message is:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
>   Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

I created a new disk in Virtual PC 512M, and download .iso file(s), it gives the same error whether I use 32 bit or 64 bit one. I even checked the option on SETUP for Virtualization : which is **Enabled**.

Does anyone know how to fix it? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying the same error occurs whether the VM is 32-bit or 64-bit, or that this error occurs *even when your use a 32-bit Ubuntu `.iso` image*?

Comment: You may have to run 32-bit Ubuntu with PAE support. That may not be possible in XP-mode of MS Virtual PC (but I have no own experience on that).

Comment: Please try with the Xubuntu i386 ISO in order to bypass any PAE issues: http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/12.04/release/xubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: Just for the sake of gathering information, what CPU is the physical system using? Using a 32-bit version of Ubuntu should avoid problems with the kernel looking for an x86-64 CPU, but details about your system may help us provide advice on configuring VirtualPC.

Answer (score 2):

After a little more reading, it seems like VirtualPC is intended for use mainly as a way of running older MS Windows operating systems and applications.  One of the major selling points for VirtualPC is that you can run WindowsXP apps without running a separate instance of a complete Windows XP virtual machine (like VMWare Fusion on OSX).  That functionality, however, would **not** be available at all if you try to install a non-Windows operating system in VirtualPC.

Your best bet, if you are truly interested in running Ubuntu inside Windows 7, is to try one of the other virtualization offerings out there.  I'd recommend [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), which is available at no cost, and has a [wealth of documentation](http://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20install%20ubuntu%2012.04%20virtualbox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs) on how to install other operating systems.

Someone has even put together helpful, illustrated, step-by-step instructions on [how to install Ubuntu inside VirtualBox](http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-run-ubuntu-inside-windows-using.html) (too long to repost full contents here).

Answer (score 0):

You can try my method (in VirtualBox and BIOS)

In bios, restart your device and press <kbd>f2</kbd> quickly (sometimes del) and find AMD VT (supported amd processors) or find INTEL VT (supported intel processord) and enable it.

iI your processor doesn't support vt technology, enable PAE in
(new version method):

**VirtualBox > Virtual OS settings > system/mainboard > extended features: enable PAE/NX**

old version method:

**VirtualBox > Virtual OS settings > general > advanced > enable PAE/NX**